# Sign In two different types of users

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am developing an App for home tuition using Flutter and Firebase, but I am having a problem in my SignIn screen as I want to send teacher and student to different profile screens but I can't make a good logic for it. I tried assigning a string that will be compared to send each User to respective screens but it did not work as it provides me with either null. Here is a code of my SignIn Screen.

```
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';
import 'package:etutor/Animation/FadeAnimation.dart';
import 'package:etutor/ReusableMaterial/BackArrow.dart';
import 'package:etutor/ReusableMaterial/Constants.dart';
import 'package:etutor/ReusableMaterial/Loading.dart';
import 'package:etutor/ReusableMaterial/ReusableButton.dart';
import 'package:etutor/ReusableMaterial/ReusableCard.dart';
import 'package:etutor/Screens/Index.dart';
import 'package:etutor/Screens/ProfileSelection.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;

  String email;
  String password;
  bool pass1 = true;
  String userType;
  String loggedInUserID;
  bool loading = false;

  void showErrorMessage(String title, String description) {
    AwesomeDialog(
      context: context,
      dialogType: DialogType.ERROR,
      animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
      tittle: title,
      desc: description,
    ).show();
  }

  Future getUserType() async {
    userType = (await _firestore
        .collection('userData')
        .document(loggedInUserID)
        .get()) as String;
    print(userType);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loading
        ? Loading()
        : Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
            body: SafeArea(
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 35),
                  FadeAnimation(
                    0.5,
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Sign In',
                        style: kHeadingStyle,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  BackArrow(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FadeAnimation(
                        0.5,
                        Text(
                          'Enter your details to access your Account.',
                          style: kTextLineStyle,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 45),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
                    child: FadeAnimation(
                      0.5,
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(84, 104, 255, .3),
                                blurRadius: 20,
                                offset: Offset(0, 10),
                              )
                            ]),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ReusableCard(
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                email = value;
                              },
                              hintLabel: 'Email',
                            ),
                            ReusablePasswordCard(
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                password = value;
                              },
                              hintLabel: 'Password',
                              pass: pass1,
                              onPress: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  pass1 = !pass1;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28),
                      ),
                      FadeAnimation(
                        0.5,
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text(
                            'Forgot Password ?',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: kBlueColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  FadeAnimation(
                    0.5,
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Don\'t have an Account ?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Color(0xFF546270),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  FadeAnimation(
                    0.5,
                    Center(
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ProfileSelection(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'SIGN UP',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: kBlueColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  FadeAnimation(
                    0.5,
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ReusableButton(
                          label: 'Continue',
                          onPress: () async {
                            if (!email.contains('@') ||
                                email == null ||
                                !email.contains('.com')) {
                              showErrorMessage('Invalid Email',
                                  'The email you entered is wrong, please check your email format and try again');
                            } else if (password == null) {
                              showErrorMessage('Invalid Password',
                                  'The password field is empty');
                            } else {
                              try {
                                setState(() {
                                  loading = true;
                                });

                                FirebaseUser signedInUser =
                                    (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                            email: email, password: password))
                                        .user;
                                if (!signedInUser.isEmailVerified) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    loading = false;
                                  });
                                  AwesomeDialog(
                                          context: context,
                                          dialogType: DialogType.ERROR,
                                          animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
                                          tittle: 'Error!',
                                          desc:
                                              'Your email has not been verified please verify your email first')
                                      .show();
                                } else {
                                  if (signedInUser != null) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      loggedInUserID = signedInUser.uid;
//                                      print(loggedInUserID);
                                    });
                                  }

                                  while (loggedInUserID == null) {}
                                  if (loggedInUserID != null) {
                                    getUserType();
                                    setState(() {
                                      loading = false;
                                    });
                                    print(loggedInUserID);
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            Index(loggedInUserID),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }
                                }
                              } catch (e) {
                                print(e);
                                showErrorMessage('Error', e);
                              }
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns null because your `getUserType()` function is async and when you check the user type it doesn't wait for your function to complete and return the data.

You must wait for data to be retrieved on way doing it is by using `await`

```
if (loggedInUserID != null) {
    await getUserType();
    setState(() {
    loading = false;
});
```